# Is drawRect ---- leaking memory

Tags: ios, uiview, memory-leaks, uiimage, drawrect

I am currenty seeing a problem with memory leaks, it seems to come from this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(offScreenBuffer);
    UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    [uiImage drawInRect:self.bounds];
    [uiImage release];

}
```

this method is called from touches events ...

```
-(void)drawPoint:(UITouch *)touch {  

    currentLoc = [[PointLocation alloc] init];

    currentLoc.location = [touch locationInView:self];

    self.previousPoint = self.point;

    self.point = currentLoc;
    [self drawToBuffer];

    [currentLoc release];

}
```

and this is draw to buffer....

```
-(void)drawToBuffer {


    CGFloat color[4] = {R,G,B,A};

    if (self.previousPoint != nil) {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(offScreenBuffer, color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]);

    CGContextBeginPath(offScreenBuffer);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(offScreenBuffer, lane);
    CGContextSetLineCap(offScreenBuffer, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(offScreenBuffer, previousPoint.location.x, previousPoint.location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(offScreenBuffer, point.location.x, point.location.y);

    CGContextDrawPath(offScreenBuffer, kCGPathStroke);

}
 [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

this is really slow....:( And I don't know why...

Every single time I draw in the selected view, this is called, but every time I need to create an image and show it on the screen. Is there any possibility how to do this another way??

Comment: There's no leak here, as you release everything. You have another problem, in another place.

Comment: "I am currently seeing a problem with memory leaks"; What tool shows you these leaks? The first tool to use to find memory leaks would be the analyzer. (In the Xcode menu bar Product->Analyze)

Comment: sure, the tools aren't showing leaks, but in this code i am moving and passing whole images..... I'm sure there is a problem...:( But I need this code to show what is painted...

Comment: but my question is is any possibility how to do the same different way???

Comment: There is at least one slightly different way to get bitmaps drawn in drawRect, and at least 2 more ways to get bitmaps displayed outside of using a drawRect.  But that wasn't your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code inside drawRect should not be showing any leaks, as the images are properly released.

Comment: You 're definitely right but when I run this API on iPad everything is great till I run it on iPhone..... now I fixed all problems with leaking but  the Api on iPhone is still very slow.....

Answer (score 0):

Given this information the only possible leak that I can imagine could be related to `offScreenBuffer`.
If you show more code or the instruments traces it might help find the problem.

Also given the "SIZE" of the memory leak you can see if it is the image which if leaking or its something else and you are misreading the instruments reports.

Comment: sure,but it only the CGContextRef *offScreenBuffer for showing image in which I painted before....:(

Comment: OK, still make sure you release that properly. By the way why wont you move to ARC?

Comment: How could that be a problem? for using ARC? or for proper memory management? By the way lots of there types of animations could be done using core animation facilities or other facilities built into iOS. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have too.

Comment: But the arc still doesn't solve the problem of slowing down the API on iPhone..:(

Comment: Sure man but i solve painting=) But thanks, but i don't want to rebuilt more than month of work:(

Answer (score 0):

I currently solved this problem. It was a problem of getting saved to data memory one again a image of defined size. I need to create a drawing api from the beginning, it took some time, but it was better than updating unfunctional version. Thanks all for cooperation =)