# Poor drawing performance on iPhone, on iPad works great

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have problem with my app. It is developed for both devices. On iPad it works great, but if I run it on iPhone it sucks. It slows down a lot. Note:I use storyboards and same View controllers and delegates for both devices.

Any suggestions?

[Is drawRect ---- leaking memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926386/is-drawrect-leaking-memory)

It is iOS 5, On iPhone 3, 3S, 4, and 4S. Everyone is experiencing problems with this. 
It draws in response to finger movement. 
If I touch the screen, the line I draw falls behind..... and I don't know why.
On iPad it works great .

maybe but main there could be problem here

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(offScreenBuffer);
    UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    [uiImage drawInRect:self.bounds];
    [uiImage release];

}
```

this method is called from touches events ...

```
-(void)drawPoint:(UITouch *)touch {

currentLoc = [[PointLocation alloc] init];

currentLoc.location = [touch locationInView:self];

self.previousPoint = self.point;

self.point = currentLoc;
[self drawToBuffer];

[currentLoc release];
}
```

and this is draw to buffer....

```
-(void)drawToBuffer {

CGFloat color[4] = {R,G,B,A};

if (self.previousPoint != nil) {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(offScreenBuffer, color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]);

    CGContextBeginPath(offScreenBuffer);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(offScreenBuffer, lane);
    CGContextSetLineCap(offScreenBuffer, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(offScreenBuffer, previousPoint.location.x, previousPoint.location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(offScreenBuffer, point.location.x, point.location.y);

    CGContextDrawPath(offScreenBuffer, kCGPathStroke);

}
 [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

but now i really don't know and have no idea...:(

creating offscreenbuffer 
-(CGContextRef)setupBuffer {

```
CGSize size = self.bounds.size;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, size.width*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);


return context;
```

}

Comment: Way too few details. It's like saying: *My car doesn't work. It drives on one road but not the other. Why?* Can you guess what the problem is with the car? Neither can we guess what your problem is. You need to provide more info and possibly even some code.

Comment: Will not be able to help you unless you are way more specific. Are you talking public or private API ? What does your debug log and memory allocation say ?

Comment: You might as well ask: "I have a question; what is my answer?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926386/is-drawrect-leaking-memory

Comment: could you show where and how you create and modify `offScreenBuffer`?

Comment: calling `drawRect:` in your code serves no purpose unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: offscreen buffer isn't modified whole time until it comes to drawRect:)

Comment: -(CGContextRef)setupBuffer {
    
    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
    
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, size.width*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    
    
    return context;
}

Comment: that is creating offscreen buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut a few corners by drawing the `CGImage` directly, without the `UIImage` step, using

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cgImage);
```

this will probably flip the image vertically, but that can be fixed. It may or may not make a difference, I don't know what overhead `UIImage` adds.

As for strange performance differences, you may want to look into the memory alignment of the underlying bitmap. (see the comments for my question regarding `offscreenBuffer`)

**update** regarding the code shown in the updated question

The code is not really efficient. For every touch event, you have this happening:

1. a call to `-drawPoint:`
2. allocation, init, release and dealloc of `PointLocation`, assignment using setter (`self.point = ...`)
3. a call to `-drawToBuffer`
4. setting stroke color/line style/line cap on your offscreen context
5. beginpath, movetopoint, addlinetopoint, drawpath

these may each not take a lot of time, but added together it might just make a difference if you would reduce the complexity. Per item you can try the following:

1. reduce the number of calls, by doing some stuff directly in/from the touch event functions
2. don't box the CGPoint in an object, but just use two CGPoint ivars instead of properties. So it will look like: `lastPoint = currPoint; currPoint = point;`, with the rest of the code adapted of course
3. see point 1.
4. if you keep the same CGContext backing throughout the lifecycle of the view, you only need to set these once on initialization. Otherwise, if you do need to switch styles once in a while, use `CGContextSaveGState(offscreenBuffer)` and `CGContextRestoreGState(offscreenBuffer)` to see if it is faster
5. there is a neat function for just drawing a simple line: `CGContextStrokeLineSegments`, which may be faster. Use it like this:

   `CGPoint points[2] = { lastPoint, currPoint };`
    `CGContextStrokeLineSegments(offscreenBuffer,points,2);`
6. profile/profile/profile: **test** to see if changes make things faster, by measuring rendering time. At the top: `NSDate *tstart = [NSDate date];` and at the bottom `NSLog(@"drawRect took %f ms",-[tstart timeIntervalSinceNow]*1000);`

You can tackle each of these points individually and check if it still works.

Good luck!

Comment: this makes me draw upside down :d if i take my mouse up, it draws down....funny:D:D:D

Comment: do you know how to fix it..?:d

Comment: yes, but please first check if it solves your performance problem, otherwise you can just leave the `UIImage` in. And please answer the other questions in the comments as well to pinpoint the real issues.

Comment: ok I would test it and will see

Comment: @RadimHalfar I added anything I can think of to make your code faster.

Comment: well, there's actually some more things you can try, but this should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

Check the drawing code for any hardcoded values like this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
```

then make it

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: this is not working for me but thanks